# Двоеточие, пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте. Надо двоеточие после слова "являются"? "Основными чертами этого стиля являются роскошь, изящество и гармоничность пропорций."

Answer (score 3):

1) **В основном (нейтральном)** варианте двоеточие при отсутствии обобщающего слова **не ставится**: "Основными чертами этого стиля являются роскошь, изящество и гармоничность пропорций".

2) Постановка двоеточия **возможна**, но при этом появляются новые оттенки значения и меняется интонационная структура предложения: "Основными чертами Этого стиля явлЯются: **(понижение тона, предупредительная пауза)**  роскошь, изящество и гармоничность пропорций."

Перераспределение тонических ударений приводит к **логическому выделению** слова "этого", что по смыслу соответствует **сравнению с предыдущим стилем**.

Answer (score 1):

Двоеточие после слова *являются* здесь можно поставить.

[Употребление двоеточия](http://fb.ru/article/108002/kogda-stavitsya-dvoetochie-instruktsiya-po-vyipolneniyu-zadaniy)

Двоеточие ставится в тех предложениях, в которых используются обобщающие слова и однородные члены предложения. Этот знак препинания нужно ставить после обобщающих слов и ***перед перечислением***.

***Двоеточие ставится в предложении, если идет перечисление чего-либо, но нет обобщающего слова.*** Пример: Из сумки торчали: кошелек, документы, расческа и паспорт. Из квартиры вышли: женщина, мужчина и ребенок.